# Nokogiri: non-destructively print node without its children

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a piece of ruby code to replace the value of an attribute:

```ruby
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
require "nokogiri"
    
xml = <<-eos
<a blubb="blah">
  <b>irrelevant</b>
  <b>also irrelevant</b>
  <b blubb="blah">
    <c>irrelevant</c>
    <c>irrelevant</c>
  </b>
  <b blubb="foo">
    <c>irrelevant</c>
    <c>irrelevant</c>
  </b>
</a>
eos

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml) { |config| config.noent }
doc.xpath("//*[@blubb='blah']").each {|node|
  puts "Node before:\n#{node.to_s}" ## replace me!
  node['blubb'] = "NEW"
  puts "Node after:\n#{node.to_s}" ## replace me!
}
```

When i execute this code, i get the whole `node` element printed, but I only need to see the start tag to confirm that my script works correctly. Is there a way to display only the start tags of `node`, or at least only the element itself without its child nodes? The important thing is that the node itself doesn't change when printed (beside the replacement in the attribute), so removing the children is not an option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can print `name` and `attribute_nodes` of the node

```
doc.xpath("//*[@blubb='blah']").each {|node|
  puts "Node before:\n #{node.name} "+node.attribute_nodes.reduce('') { |out, n| out+="#{n.name}=#{n.value}'"}
  node['blubb'] = "NEW"
  puts "Node after:\n #{node.name} "+node.attribute_nodes.reduce('') { |out, n| out+="#{n.name}='#{n.value}'"}
}
```

Comment: I hoped for a more compact solution, but this will do. Thanks.